# How can I get the maximum value of specific fields in a CSV text file?

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk

Each line in my **text file** example (CSV, comma separated) is like:

```
2016-01-10,23:56:07,10,71,47
```

As can be seen, fields 3, 4 and 5 are **numeric** values.

For each line, I would like to get only the **maximum** value of fields **3 and 4**. Something like:

```
awk -F ',' '{print max($3,$4)}'
```

(probably not a real AWK syntax, this one, but it is the closest I can think about).
So, for the above line, the resulting number would be '71' .

Example with more lines:

```
2016-01-10,23:53:07,6,99,41
2016-01-10,23:54:07,10,88,44
2016-01-10,23:55:07,31,71,46
2016-01-10,23:56:07,71,10,47
```

The results:

```
99
88
71
71
```

How can this be done on **Linux shell**?
I have suggested AWK, but any other solutions are OK.

Answer (score 7):

this one-liner may help:

```
awk -F, '{print ($3>$4?$3:$4)}' file
```

Comment: Cute. Nice and simple. AWK is really powerful, so it was my suggested method.

Comment: awk is good at those tasks. col. based data, specially, with math. processing.

Answer (score 2):

Just Bash:

```
while IFS=, read -r _ _ f3 f4 _; do echo "$(( f3 > f4 ? f3 : f4 ))"; done < infile
```

If field 3 and 4 can contain non-integers, this can be extended using `bc` to support floats (making it even more obvious how the awk solution is preferrable):

```
while IFS=, read -r _ _ f3 f4 _; do
    bc -l <<< "if ($f3 > $f4) $f3 else $f4"
done < infile
```

<sup>`else` is a GNU extension and not supported by POSIX `bc`. Use `if ($f3 > $f4) $f3; if ($f4 >= $f3) $f4` for POSIX conformance.</sup>

Comment: try changing the `99` in first line into `99.04`, what do you get then?

Comment: Garbage - but I dared assuming the values are integers, based on the example. Let me add some `bc` prettiness, though ;)

Comment: POSIX solutions use to be preferable, but some embedded devices include `if...then` and `while` commands, but not `awk`, so this is a good solution for me too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more control over formatting or have quoted cvs fields, Python is a good choice:

```
$ python -c "
> import csv, fileinput
> for line in csv.reader(fileinput.input()): 
>    print max(map(float, line[2:4]))
> " /tmp/file.csv
99.0
88.0
71.0
71.0
```