# working with Olympic.csv. I am trying to find the "Which country had the highest number of gold medal. getting result as whole row

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

working with Olympic.csv. I am trying to find the "Which country had the highest number of gold(column=>"Gold") medal. getting result as whole row

```
def answer_one():
    return df["Gold"].max()
max = answer_one()
print(df.[df["Gold"] == max])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the maximum value of specific fields in a CSV text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731937/how-can-i-get-the-maximum-value-of-specific-fields-in-a-csv-text-file)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate bit more on your question?

Comment: I am working with olypics csv(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table). it contains country names and medals got in summer winter Olympics. I want to get the name of country which got highest number of gold in summer olypics( summer gold- column name-> "Gold"). By using the above written code am getting whole row but i need only country name

Comment: `df.loc[df['Gold'].idxmax(),'Nation']`